# resize an image based on the devices width and height

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to resize an image in asp.net Visual studio V2008, c#

```
using (Graphics newgraphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBackgroundImage))
{
newgraphics.Clear(Color.FromArgb(-1));
if ((float)oldbmp.Width / (float)Width == (float)oldbmp.Height / (float)Height)            
  {
    newgraphics.DrawImage(oldbmp, 0, 0, Width, Height);
  }
}
```

I have entered the above code, but I get the following errors on a build.

the Graphic.DrawImage is overloaded. It is expecting , int, int, Rectangle, graphicsunit

Anyone have any suggestions?

Much appreciated
Rachael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue

- In InitializeComponent  I added the following two lines
  ```
          'this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(96F, 96F);'
          'this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;'
  ```
  This explains why I did that
  [CLick Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229649(v=vs.90).aspx)
- I attached the image to the form Skin 
        - As it was currently being draw in the paint override method
        - The code above does not re-size images drawn in the paint override method
- Set the sizemode to Stretch Image and then will check the DPI of the device 
            and reset the image accordingly

That should do the trick

Thanks jundev for your patient.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you've provided, it seems like you are not providing the correct arguments for DrawImage method.

Can you confirm what type 'oldbmp' belongs to ? It should be an 'Image' type in order to satisfy one of the overload requirements.

Below is all the overloads for DrawImage method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage(v=vs.110).aspx

Based on your code, below overload should do the job.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ab36azw(v=vs.110).aspx

Have you tried using 0.0F instead of 0 ?

Comment: Hi Jundev, what do you mean by 0.0F instead of 0?

Comment: Basically what is happening is that I am running a mobile application and when the device screen size changes (the original is 240 by 268 (width * height) , the new device is 480 * 536. the image is not resized to fit the new device.

Comment: I have looked at System.Drawing.Image and it doesnt have the option of Image.FromFile - It only has three overload methods. .equals, .fromHbitmap and ReferenceEquals. I have Visual Studio 2008, .net v3.5, Is it maybe that my .net version is too old and the new overload methods are not avaiable?

Comment: Okay I have discovered that the DPI from the two devices I am working on are different - 192 DPI and 96 DPI, I will also have to allow for anyother devices with different DPI. So instead of creating an image for each DPI type , is there another work around which will resize the images for me?

Comment: 0.0F means floating point. In your parameters, you've given zeros, and this could sometimes be considered as an int. I asked you to try floating point because one of the links I gave you contains the following overload DrawImage(Image, float, float, float, float)

Comment: I'm sure that the overloads are available since .Net 2.0. You could verify that going to the link I sent you, and clicking on the drop-down that has framework versions.

Comment: I'm not sure if it has to do with device sizes if you are getting compile time errors on method overloading. Please check what type 'oldbmp' belongs to. Because that's your first argument in DrawImage method, and it needs to be of type System.Drawing.Image. The rest should all be of type float, as mentioned above.

Comment: If possible, please post any more code or screenshots that you think might make your question more clearer.